# php query mongodb with ampersand (&)

Tags: php, mongodb

I have a data in mongodb which name has "&" in it. Something like "Bed & Breakfast".
When I update its name, it remains only "Bed " in database.
I thought okay I can just modify directly in mongo shell. But it turns out that the find query from php didn't work either. 
I'm sure I have a data in mongodb has a name "Bed & Breakfast", and I can find this data in mongodb, but not from php. All other data without "&" work fine.
How can I fix this?

```
$connection = new Mongo( "localhost:27017" );

$db = $connection->selectDB("database");
$collection = $db->selectCollection("room");

if(isset($_GET['name'])){
    $name = $_GET['name'];
}
$filter = array('name' => $name);
$cursor = $collection->find($filter);
if($cursor->hasNext()){
        foreach($cursor as $data){
                echo $data;
        }
}else{
        echo 'null';
}
```

Comment: Hi, I updated the code. Thanks. Just a simple find query from php.

Comment: What does the update query look like?

Comment: Please also use "new MongoClient" instead of "new Mongo".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are taking the name from PHP "GET" .

When GET parameters are received, PHP splits them on the basis of "&" , hence the when:

$name = $_GET['name']

this line is processed, $name is set to "Bed " rather than "Bed & Breakfast".

To fix this either use post to sent the parameters,if possible,

else, apply URL encode to the parameters you pass to the GET string.

Reference for urlencode-

https://www.php.net/urlencode